# 'spinner' does not appear right after call it

Tags: javascript, spinner

I am using js to show a 'spinner' for waiting state when loading data. Call `showWaiting()` to show 'spinner' and `hideWaiting()` to hide 'spinner' when data loading completed. 'Spinner' does not appear after calling `showWaiting()` as expected, it only appears after data finished loading (`loadData1()`). Please help me. Thanks

Below is the source code:

js source code:

```
this.showWaiting();
this.loadData1();
this.hideWaiting();
this.function1();

showWaiting: function () {
          $("#progressbar").css("display", "block");
          $("#waiting_popup").show();
          $("#progressbar").progressbar({
              value: false
          });
      }
```

html of spinner:

```
<div id="waiting_popup" style="z-index: 999999; position: relative;">
        <div class="ui-widget-overlay ui-front"></div>
        <div id="progressbar" style="width: 300px; margin: 18% auto; display:none;">
            <div style="float: left;margin-left: 35%; margin-top: 5px;font-weight: bold;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;">Loading...</div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is strictly single threaded, so there is nothing happening in the browser user interface as long as your code is running. You have to end your function after showing the spinner, and use a timeout to start the loading after the browser has had a chance to update the interface:

```
this.showWaiting();
var th = this;
window.setTimeout(function(){
  th.loadData1();
  th.hideWaiting();
  th.function1();
}, 0);
```

You should check if you can make your loading asynchronous. If your spinner is an animated gif, it won't move either as long as your code is running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I try this but it does not work because after those functions I have some functions use result from loadData1(). So when loadData1() is in timeout, functions follow it will be error. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @HuyVo: The timeout makes the code asynchronous, so anything that uses the data that you load has to go in the callback function, like the `function1` call in the code above. Come to think of it, you also need to catch the value of `this`, as the context is different in the callback, and you were using `this` to call the methods. I adjusted the code above.